# Android MainActivity cannot be cast to Bottomsheetlistener

Tags: android, fragment

i have created a Bottomsheet which needs to be called from a Fragment. I try to call it this way:

```
  CreateSurveyBottomSheet survey = new CreateSurveyBottomSheet();
  survey.show(getChildFragmentManager(), "Survey Sheet");
```

Afterwards my Bottomsheet should send data back to the fragment :

```
 private void sendData(SurveyObject object) {

    mlistener.onButtonClicked(object);
}

public interface BottomSheetListener{
    void onButtonClicked(SurveyObject object);
}


@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);



        mlistener = (BottomSheetListener) this.getContext();


}
```

And i want to receive it in my fragment:

```
   public void onButtonClicked(SurveyObject objecti) {
    object = objecti;

    IsSurveyExisting = true;


}
```

Unfortunately my app crashes when i try to call my Bottomsheet Fragment with this error:

```
    java.lang.ClassCastException: MainActivity cannot be cast to CreateSurveyBottomSheet$BottomSheetListener
```

the error is located in my OnAttach Method in my bottomsheet. Would be great if someone could help me

Comment: does your activity implement `BottomSheetListener`? Also `this.getContext();` is not made to give you an Activity

Comment: change in the on attatch method 'this.Context' to just plain 'this'. Also makes sure your main activity implements the interface BottomSheetListener

Comment: @SteelToe `this` is the fragment, not activity

Comment: Got it, so make sure your fragment implements `BottomSheetListener` and change from this.getContext, to just plain this

Comment: Let me know if this solves your problem

Comment: @SteelToe this is not what he asks

Comment: the error is fixed, but then i receive the data in my mainactivity not in my fragment but i want to get the data in my fragment, where i also call it

Comment: exactly @VladyslavMatviienko

Answer (score 1):

Make your MainActivity implement CreateSurveyBottomSheet$BottomSheetListener